# Using a while loop to restrict user to input only integers in the concept of operator overloading in Python

Tags: python, oop, operator-overloading

how can I use a for loop in OOP to display an error message when a user inputs something other than an integer for variables a & b, and loop it until the user inputs an integer?  This is in the context of operator overloading in Python

```
class Number:
    
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        
        
    def __mul__(self, other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        return x
    
a = Number(int(input("Enter a number: ")))
 
b = Number(int(input("Enter another number: ")))
 
print("\nThose two numbers added together are",a*b)
```

Comment: Use the isinstance() method

Answer (score 0):

```
class Number:
    
    def __init__(self): # taking in put in init! This will run whenever an object of the class is created
        while True:
            try:
                self.x = int(input("Enter a number: ")) # trying to convert the input to int
                break
            except Exception as exp:
                print(f"Here is your ERROR: {exp}. RETRY!")  # if conversion failed, retry!
        
        
    def __mul__(self, other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        return x
    
a = Number()
 
b = Number()
 
print("\nThose two numbers added together are",a*b)
```